# Centralized and local syslog

Tags: syslog, debian-jessie

Right now I have my clients send any syslog messages to my centralized syslog server. However, if that server went down, I would be unable to capture any logs. Is there an option to have syslog write the message locally and remotely? Or if the remote server is down, then write locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to config both on that remote host

```
*.* @YourServerThatReceivingFromThisMachine
*.* /var/log/messages
```