# How to make my Window system a Syslog server

Tags: linux, windows, networking, router, logging

I have my D-link router which can forward its logs to a syslog server. Now, I do not have any syslog server. Hence, I want to make my Windows machine a syslog server to get those logs from the D-link router.

Post that, I want to forward these logs (collected from D-link router) to my SIEM (Centralized Log Management) platform.

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

People in comment told me that I MUST to answer to you question:

> Can somebody help me on this?

Let then follow community rules and fill technical question with bureaucracy :(
My answer is - yes, I will try to help you :)

Well, there are few choices, you can run `syslog` "natively" under windows by 
installing [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Select `syslog` on installation. Run `syslog` as Windows service. (Use [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm) but setup `syslog` as a service instead of SSH)
Other way, you can install some guest unix based operation system in virtual machine, such as VirtualBox or native Windows virtual machine and run inside of it `syslog` server that will be accessible by you router over network. Not so long ago I provided a help how to setup syslog, so it can accept connection from a network, look it here: https://superuser.com/a/945570/164837
On the router side, just point to IP address where syslog is running.

Comment: Could you please show me, how to answer to the question (actually asked): "Can somebody help me on this?" Do you really think I should answer: "Yes, I can" :)

Comment: As about "Your answer should include all relevant information within your answer." - I thought I gave all information needed how to run syslog under windows. If you know any other RELIABLE and CONVENIENT way how to do that, I would appreciate if you will share it with us. If you don't know what syslog is, just ask, and I will try to explain it to you, but don't expect me to be a google who serves multiple relevant content for free. I trying to answer precisely instead of staffing answer with ALL relevant info. I really don't get it, are you expecting a course about operation systems?

Comment: What else should be detailed? I gave a link to all documentation needed to achieve what OP is asking. And this info would be actual even over time, since official gygwin provider will keep this info up to dated. No, really, could you please help me to understand what do you mean. This is pretty simple, download, answer a question on install and that is it. If there would be some misunderstanding it is better to ask again. I pretty sure that rephrasing official documentation here is bad help

Comment: Your answer by itself does not answer the author's question.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand better requirement of this site.

Comment: I edited my answer, is it looks better now? Or you still can not figure out how to setup syslog on windows? It is not sarcasm, seriously, ask, and I try to help you

Comment: I think I gave more than enough directions how to do that. Nobody can replace original documentation. If somebody looking to step-by-step detailed "how-to" - it is a way for looking to get a free service instead of learn themselves of particular concept. syslog isn't so complicated, even so it better to help people to understand than do their job instead of them. It is very wide subject to explain concepts behind unix in a single particular question I think. Correct me pls, if I'm wrong. I'd like this forums and got answers to my questions and I trying to just help back some1 as appreciation

Comment: I still can't get it what exactly missed from my answer you are looking. Help me please to correct it so it would be usable not only for particular OP, but any lurkers who come here from google. I think it is better to wait for additional question from OP if he didn't understand something instead of be a telepathic and try to guess and  fill with useless information my answer.